# "Maximum stack depth reached: 3" when doing String.replaceAll()

Tags: apex, limits, regular-expressions

I am getting a strange "Maximum stack depth reached: 3" when doing a String.replaceAll() with bigger Regex on a quite big string (40 lines of text).
I am trying to remove any comments and literal strings out of Apex Class source code.

```
...
private static final Pattern COMMENTS_LITERALS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile('(/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/)|(//.*)|\'.*\'');

String sourceCode = 'long text around 40';
String cleanedBody;

Matcher commentsLiteralsMatch = COMMENTS_LITERALS_PATTERN.matcher(original.Body);
if(commentsLiteralsMatch.find()) {
     cleanedBody = commentsLiteralsMatch.replaceAll('');     
}
...
```

But the small number 3 really looks to low for me to be any limit.

Do you have an explanation for this or did you experience similar behaviors?!

Comment: Can you post the regex?

Comment: Sounds pretty strange, would help to create a case with Salesforce Support about this.

Comment: tomlogic Sure sorry that I forgot to post a code example yesterday.

Comment: This is still unsolved. I am searching comments and string literals in multiple ApexClass bodies and removing them by doing a replaceall(...,''); I run into Stack depth limits there.

Answer (score 8):

My guess is that you're reaching a limit on nested groups in your regular expression.

You could try splitting it into two separate match patterns:

```
'/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/'
'(//.*)|\'.*\''
```

And making two passes on `sourceCode`.

As for matching C-style comments, check out this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462843/improving-fixing-a-regex-for-c-style-block-comments).

Comment: Splitting the regex didn't work. Besides that it must be something different as in my code I have other regexps that have 10 and more  groups.

Comment: In the working regexps, are those groups nested three levels deep `(((A)))` or just lots of groups `((A)(B))(C)(D)((E)(F))` with less than three levels of nesting?

Comment: Oh now I understand. The 3 in the error message might come from 3 levels of groups?! You are right the others have a max grouping of 2. I try to rewrite the regexp with 3 levels.