# I am getting Exception FATAL_ERROR|System. LimitException: Maximum stack depth reached: 12

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I am trying to execute an apex test class where i am getting the following error

> EcedoSyncServiceTest updateContact Fail System.LimitException: Maximum
>   stack depth reached: 3
>   Class.EcedoConverter.convertEcedoOrganizationAndEcedoConnectionsToFullState:
>   line 74, column 1 Class.EcedoSyncService.getEcedoStateForOrganization:
>   line 26, column 1 Class.EcedoSyncServiceTest.updateContact: line 38,
>   column 1
>
> EcedoSyncServiceTest updateAccount Fail System.LimitException: Maximum
>   stack depth reached: 3
>   Class.EcedoConverter.convertEcedoOrganizationAndEcedoConnectionsToFullState:
>   line 74, column 1 Class.EcedoSyncService.getEcedoStateForOrganization:
>   line 26, column 1 Class.EcedoSyncServiceTest.updateAccount: line 78,
>   column 1

_______________________________________________________________Updated

> 15:46:41.328 (6328249333)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Maximum
>   stack depth reached: 12
>   Class.EcedoConverter.convertEcedoOrganizationAndEcedoConnectionsToFullState:
>   line 74, column 1 Class.EcedoSyncService.getEcedoStateForOrganization:
>   line 26, column 1 Class.FlowStep_RefreshDataFromEcedo.execute: line
>   19, column 1 Class.FlowStepExecutor.executeImpl: line 23, column 1
>   Class.FlowStepExecutor.execute: line 6, column 1
>   Class.FlowRunner.runStep: line 153, column 1
>   Class.FlowRunner.runNewOrReadPersistedStep: line 108, column 1
>   Class.FlowRunner.runSteps: line 65, column 1
>   Class.FlowRunner.runFlowWithState: line 57, column 1
>   Class.FlowRunner.runFlow: line 37, column 1
>   Class.Controller_FlowRunPage.runFlow: line 66, column 1
>   Class.Controller_FlowRunPage.runFromPage: line 50, column 1
>   15:46:41.328 (6328267594)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Controller_FlowRunPage
>   invoke(runFromPage) 15:46:41.353
>   (6353755979)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_BEGIN 15:46:41.353
>   (6353755979)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|SOQL operations|
>   Class.Util_DML.caseByid: line 273, column 1:
>   com.salesforce.api.Database.query(String): executed 1 time in 28 ms
>   Class.Util_DML.tasksByCase: line 287, column 1:
>   com.salesforce.api.Database.query(String): executed 1 time in 11 ms
>   Class.Controller_FlowRunPage.__sfdc_showDebug: line 7, column 1:
>   [SELECT Name,Id FROM Profile WHERE Id =: profileId]: executed 1 time
>   in 4 ms
>
> 15:46:41.353 (6353755979)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling
>   information for SOSL operations 15:46:41.353
>   (6353755979)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling information for DML
>   operations 15:46:41.353 (6353755979)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|method
>   invocations| External entry point: public System.PageReference
>   runFromPage(): executed 1 time in 6295 ms Class.HttpClient.get: line
>   55, column 1: private String executeRequest(System.HttpRequest):
>   executed 8 times in 5992 ms Class.HttpClient.executeRequest: line 111,
>   column 1: global System.HttpResponse send(ANY): executed 8 times in
>   5960 ms Class.EcedoSyncService.getEcedoStateForOrganization: line 20,
>   column 1: public List
>   getConnectionContracts(String, String): executed 8 times in 4377 ms
>   Class.EcedoService.getConnectionContracts: line 151, column 1: public
>   String get(String): executed 4 times in 4322 ms
>   Class.EcedoSyncService.getEcedoStateForOrganization: line 15, column
>   1: public List getConnections(String):
>   executed 1 time in 1286 ms Class.EcedoService.getConnections: line
>   139, column 1: public String get(String): executed 1 time in 1276 ms
>   Class.EcedoSyncService.getEcedoStateForOrganization: line 13, column
>   1: public List
>   getAdvancePayments(String): executed 1 time in 177 ms
>   Class.EcedoSyncService.getEcedoStateForOrganization: line 12, column
>   1: public EcedoService.EcedoOrganization getOrganization(String):
>   executed 1 time in 172 ms Class.EcedoService.getOrganization: line
>   120, column 1: public String get(String): executed 1 time in 167 ms
>   Class.EcedoService.getAdvancePayments: line 157, column 1: public
>   String get(String): executed 1 time in 133 ms

Comment: Wait, which is it? 3, or 12?

Comment: Candidate for the 3 http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8623/maximum-stack-depth-reached-3-when-doing-string-replaceall.

Comment: @KeithC I was *just* about to say that.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yeah I found that one when looking for the 12 one...

Comment: Thanks for the update but can you please let me know what can be a possible reason , as the similar case is not resolved Thanks

Comment: So is it 3 or 12?

Comment: Its coming as 3 , and changes accordingly sometime.Can you please let me know how the change in number effect is it loop consequence or some thing else

Comment: I have updated the lines of codes , Kindly check the possibility

Comment: Sounds like something is recursivly executing Class.EcedoConverter.convertEcedoOrganizationAndEcedoConnectionsToFullState starting at: Class.Controller_FlowRunPage.runFromPage: line 50.

Comment: It works fine for all user except for one if that user is added in debug log and the steps proceed